# How to tell CPack to use the FreeBSD generator?

Tags: cmake, freebsd, cpack

I have found [several](https://www.mankier.com/7/cpack-generators) [interesting](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/2042cae9a5d9bb2f71a715022a4b6a7416c8e9e3) [links](https://www.freebsdnews.com/2017/03/02/packaging-cpack-freebsd/) talking about a [CPack generator for FreeBSD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/freebsd.html).

I would like to generate FreeBSD packages; however, whenever I attempt to generate TXZ archives (as directed by the instructions), the generated package isn't compatible with the `pkg` utility on FreeBSD. They miss the manifest file.

Obviously, CPack is generating raw archives, not `pkg`-ready archives. I assume I must be missing a step.

However, none of the links above talk about any such step.

Therefore,

**How can I tell CPack to generate a FreeBSD-ready package?**

Comment: How to tell CPack to use the FreeBSD generator?" - Use the command `cpack -G FreeBSD`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `CPack Error: Could not create CPack generator: FreeBSD`, then it lists all generators available (none of which seem related to any BSD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Original author of that code here)

So, there's two things in play here:

- you need to be on FreeBSD (so that you have *libpkg*, which is needed to do the building)
- you need to build the *devel/cmake* package with OPTIONS `CPACK` (which is not the default)

So:

- `cd /usr/ports/devel/cmake`
- `make configure` and select `CPACK`
- `make && make install`

**Then** @Tsyvarev's comment will be the right answer. For the record, the support was deemed experimental, the library API unstable, and the *pkg* authors have asked me to re-vamp the code to use the current *libpkg* API so they can drop the old one. Time, though, is the limiting factor.

Comment: Alright, following these steps did show the options - in all caps though (`FREEBSD`). But I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to pack ;-;

Comment: Do you need help with maintaining that code? I'd like to help you if you want. I wanted to integrate FreeBSD packaging in a project's CI and your work is my best bet